# Possiblity of a closed-form solution for a convex optimizaiton

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

## Problem

Is it possible to find a closed-form solution based on the system parameters ($a,b,c,d$ and $h$) for the following convex optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
\min_{\substack{t \geq 0}} \quad & b \big(\frac{a}{b} \big)^t + a \big(\frac{a}{b} \big)^{-t} + d \big(\frac{c}{d} \big)^t + c \big(\frac{c}{d} \big)^{-t} -ht \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & a > b > 0, \\
& c > d > 0, \\
& h \geq0 \\
\end{align*}
I cannot solve it when $h > 0$.

#### My attempt:

Since the function is convex with respect to $t$, it has a unique global minimum (each local minimum is the global minimum), and its minimum happens at ${t^{\ast}}$ where the derivative function is zero, $f^\prime(t^\ast)=0$.
\begin{align}
f^\prime(t) =\ln\big(\frac{a}{b} \big) \Big[ b \big(\frac{a}{b} \big)^t - a \big(\frac{a}{b} \big)^{-t} \Big] + \ln\big(\frac{c}{d} \big) \Big[ d \big(\frac{c}{d} \big)^t - c \big(\frac{c}{d} \big)^{-t} \Big] - h
\end{align}
If $h=0$, then $t^{\ast} = \frac{1}{2}$, and $f(t^{\ast}) = 2 \sqrt{ab} +2 \sqrt{cd}$. I could not proceed further due to high nonlinearity in $f^\prime(t)$ when $h > 0$.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe that a closed-forum solution exists?

Comment: @D.W. , That is a good question. I do not have any guarantee for the existence of a closed-form solution.  I thought maybe it is possible to find one for this case concerning its convexity and presence of special functions (linear and exponential) in the loss function, as is the case for $h=0$. Thanks for your comment, I edited the question.